# How do I resolve SecureChannelFailure on OSX with mono

Tags: c#, .net, macos, f#, mono

I'm trying to access https://geocoder.cit.api.here.com with .NET (F#) on mono. I'm using the `Http` helper from `FSharp.Data` using the following code:

```
let baseUrl = "https://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=1701%20McFarland%20Blvd%20E%20Tuscaloosa%09%20AL&app_id=<Some app id>&app_code=<Some app code>"

let res = Http.RequestString(baseUrl)
```

Running this for me on OSX Sierra (10.12.2) with mono version 4.6.2 yields a `SecureChannelFailure`. How do I resolve this? I have tried `mozroots --import --ask-remove` but that didn't help. There are certs in `~/.config/.mono/certs/Trust`.

I have even tried to bypass the check, since I'm just investigating the API, but that doesn't work either. The way I tried to bypass it is:

```
let callback = Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(fun _ _ _ _ -> true)
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback <- callback
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Mono *4.8+* you can assign the environment variable `MONO_TLS_PROVIDER` to `btls` before running your CIL-based `.exe`:

```
export MONO_TLS_PROVIDER=btls
mono someFSharpAssembly.exe
```

On via Xamarin Studio / Visual Studio for Mac assign it to a Run configuration:

[image]

If you then get an `HttpRequestException`:

```
Error: TrustFailure (Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED) ---> Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException
```

> It means that you do not have the certificates in the new format.   Run the tool “btls-cert-sync” to convert your existing root certificates into the new file format.   If “btls-cert-sync” complains that “The Old Trust Store does not exist”, you first need to tell Mono how to find these certificates, this page describes how to do it:

Comment: How do you go about this when running XSP Web Server? I don't seem to be able to find the option.

Comment: Found it: System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_TLS_PROVIDER", "btls"); will do the job!